# The main window in MATLAB 2014b is not appering, just the splash window

Tags: 14.04, matlab

I installed Matlab 2014b on Ubuntu 14.4 in /usr/local/MATLAB and then installed the Matlab support. Unfortunately the main Matlab window is not appearing, just the small Matlab logo window. What is the problem, and how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Probably you installed MATLAB as super user with `sudo ./install` command, and now launching it with `matlab` command or using `matlab-support` package in linux you experience this problem.
To solve it, simply grant the permission in the preferences folder with:

```
sudo chmod -R a+rw ~/.matlab
```